# Почему пространство имён для eval() так работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Функция `grid` выдаёт ошибку `name 'row' is not defined`, так как функция `eval` вызывается внутри вызова `grid`. Однако, в функции `place` такой проблемы нет, хотя команды те же. Почему `eval` внутри вызова функции меняет свое пространство имён?

```
import tkinter as tk

def _parametrize(widget, method, kvs):
  s = "widget.%s(" % method
  r = []
  for u, v in kvs:
    if v != None:
      r += ["%s = %s" % (u, v)]
  s += ", ".join(r) + ")"
  exec(s)

def place(widget, x = None, y = None, width = None, height = None):
  kvs = []
  for s in ("x", "y", "width", "height"):
    kvs += [(s, eval(s))]
  _parametrize(widget, "place", kvs)

def grid(widget, row = None, column = None, rowspan = None, columnspan = None):
  _parametrize(widget, "grid", [(s, eval(s)) for s in ("row", "column", "rowspan", "columnspan")])

r = tk.Tk()

b = Button(r, text = "Button")
place(b, 20, 20, 100, 50)
grid(b)

r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Опишите что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Comment: С тем, что я хочу сделать, проблем нет. Мне интересно, почему eval приходится использовать вне одной строки. Почему там для неё нет переменных, объявленных в функции?

Comment: Нет, у вас есть проблема: вы используете eval и exec вместо нормального решения. Но да, сути вопроса это не касается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве области видимости `eval` использует либо глобальную область видимости (если запущен вне функции), либо локальную область видимости (если запущен внутри функции).

У вас как раз случай с локальной областью видимости.

Однако, следует учитывать, что list comprehension создаёт новую локальную область видимости.

В этом легко убедиться:

```
def foo():

    a = 1

    print(locals())
    # Выведет: {'a': 1}

    [print(locals()) for x in range(1)]
    # Выведет: {'x': 0, '.0': <range_iterator object at 0x7fb02c9288a0>}

foo()
```

Как видите, в первом случае в локальной области видимости есть переменная `a`. А во втором - её нет, но есть переменная `x`.

Чтобы ваш код работал, ему можно явно передать области видимости:

```
def grid(widget, row = None, column = None, rowspan = None, columnspan = None):
    globs = globals()
    locs = locals()
    _parametrize(widget, "grid", [(s, eval(s, globs, locs))
                                  for s in ("row", "column", "rowspan", "columnspan")])
```

Но, как уже правильно сказал insolor, не надо использовать `exec` и `eval` без очень серьёзной на то причины. А в вашем случае легко можно обойтись без них.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как тогда можно обойтись без eval и exec? И какой серьёзной причиной является их использование?

Comment: Ну, например, ваш код можно переписать как-то так: https://pastebin.com/GCvsiwcn

Comment: Что касается причины для использования eval и exec, то за несколько лет работы программистом я ни разу не столкнулся с ситуацией, когда это было бы уместно и необходимо. Штатных средств языка вполне достаточно для того, чтобы обойтись без генерации кода на ходу в почти любой реальной ситуации. Возможно, их уместно использовать в каких-нибудь хитрых специализированных библиотеках или что-то вроде этого, но никакого конкретного примера навскидку придумать не могу.

Comment: Как раз в хитрой библиотеке оно у меня и есть.